# distributed PKI Certificate handling- making it user friendly

Tags: ssl-certificate, pki

I have a Server and N number of clients installed on different hosts. Each host has its self-signed certificate generated during install. The client authentication is turned ON at this point. Which means they can't communicate to each other until these certs are properly imported as described below.

Now, the server needs to import all the clients' certificates. So do all the clients from this single server. This part is really not user friendly to do it during install as either client or the server can be installed independent of each other any time. 
 What is the better way to import certs between clients and server without the user having to perform some kind of out-of-band manual steps?

PS: The PKI tool I am using can only import/export certificates on a local machine only. Assume I can't change this tool at this time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is one of the problems with PKI.  It is a pain to securely distribute certificates in an automated fashion.

In an Active Directory domain environment you already have a Kerberos trust in place.  Therefore you can use group policy to securely distribute certficates automatically.  Don't know if that would apply to you because you haven't given information about your environment/OS etc.

Comment: What are the implications of pre-populating the self-signed certificates of clients and server in the install images itself? Here is the deployment config: 1 server and 6 clients in a private secured network to be installed. The keystore in the server image already contains its own cert and 1 cert for all 6 clients. Client image has the server cert + its own cert. Once the image is installed, PKI setup has been configured completely. Which means, lets say you sell your product to 10 customers. All of them have the same certs!! But these are pvt networks. Does it matter? Assume No AD domain.

Comment: Why are self-signed certs in use?  Once these expire all nodes have to update as well - creating a terrible maintenance headache even in a private network.  Do you not have the option to use CA issued certificates?  The CA itself could be a very long lifetime (10-20 years) and then clients only need to trust it, not the individual certs.

Comment: well, self-signed certs can be created with long expiration dates (10 years) as well and there are always delivery mechanisms like patches and upgrades to the software. But my main Q still remains related to the above scenario I put.